# Gradle dependencies not found in mutil project setup?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a project setup like this

```
+ rootProject
    + module1
       + src
         build.gradle
    + module2
       + src
         build.gradle
    + src
      build.gradle
      settings.gradle
```

Content of `rootProject/build.gradle`

```
evaluationDependsOn(':module1')

apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
  compile project(':module1')
  compile project(':module2')
}


task myTask (type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'org.gradle.example.Test.Main'
    classpath runtimeClasspath
  }
```

Content of `module1/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories { 
  mavenCentral() 
}

dependencies { 
  compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9' 
}
```

Content of `module2/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

The dependencies graph

```
root --> module1 --> commons-codec
     --> module2
```

gradle report this at build with command `gradle build` in root folder

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not find commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9. Required by:
      :rootProject:unspecified > rootProject:codec:unspecified
```

if I add `dependencies` block in the rootProject's build file the it get build normally.
As you see, i already determine the dependencies in module1 build file. Why gradle keep saying that it couldnt resolve?

Do i need to put all dependencies of submodule in root build files?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I see that You're missing `settings.gradle` file which is necessary in multimodule projects. You need to create it at the same level as `rootProject/build.gradle` is located.

The content should be

```
include 'module1', 'module2'
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, to root `build.gradle` added following piece of code:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

And removed from `module1/build.gradle` the `repositories` section. Now it works. Dependencies are fetched and displayed. Currently no idea what is the explanation.

Comment: i had it, and its content is exactly what you suggest.

Comment: Well, ok. When I run `gradle build` it works perfectly fine. But there's no need for submodule dependencies to be put in rootProject's build file.

Comment: what version of gradle do you have?

Comment: can you make a try with this project `https://github.com/gradleware/oreilly-gradle-book-examples/tree/master/multiproject-individual` my project is built with same setting as this one

Comment: Hmm.. 1.11 But when I run `gradle dependencies` I see `FAILED` for `commons-codec`. Also added `guava`, result is the same. Will have a look in a moment.